# JSON Stringify Erasing Certain Attributes in Google Place Object

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, coffeescript

Encountering quite a mysterious problem here. Working with a Rails 4 app and the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

We use Google Search autocomplete to get a Google's 'place' object, then pass that place object to Rails via in order to store certain attributes (e.g. google_place_id, lat, long).

**Up until yesterday, our code was working fine.** The weird part is we didn't touch that section of code and all of a sudden this part breaks.

CoffeeScript Code:

```
saveDestinationToDatabase = (place) ->
  console.log 'Place.geo.loc: ' + place.geometry.location
  console.log 'Place.stringify: ' + JSON.stringify(place)
  $.ajax '/destinations',
    dataType: 'json'
    type: 'POST'
    async: false
    data:
      place: JSON.stringify(place)
      trip_id: tripID
    success: (data) ->
      return data
    failure: ->
      alert 'saveDestiantionToDatabase() Unsuccessful'
      return
```

The first console.log returns:
`Place.geo.loc: (41.87194, 12.567379999999957)`, indicating the Geometry object has the correct value.

The second console.log returns:
`Place.stringify: {"address_components":[{"long_name":"Italy","short_name":"IT","types":["country","political"]}],"adr_address":"<span class=\"country-name\">Italy</span>","formatted_address":"Italy","geometry":{"location":{},
...}`

Notice the geometry.location is now blank.

1. Why is JSON.stringify causing this value to be removed?
2. Why would this error start occurring without altering the code?

**Update: Solution**
Piggy-backing off Dr.Molle's answer below, I just created a JSON object from the PlaceResult details I needed. This allowed me to call Google's lat() and lng() methods before-hand.

Working Coffeescript:

```
saveDestinationToDatabase = (place) ->
  place_lat = place.geometry.location.lat()
  place_lng = place.geometry.location.lng()
  $.ajax '/destinations',
    dataType: 'json'
    type: 'POST'
    async: false
    data:
      place:
        name: place.name
        place_id: place.place_id
        formatted_address: place.formatted_address
        address_components: place.address_components
        lat: place_lat
        lng: place_lng
      trip_id: tripID
    success: (data) ->
      return data
    failure: ->
      alert 'saveDestiantionToDatabase() Unsuccessful, please alert site admins'
      return
```

Comment: Did Google slip in a `toJSON` method behind your back?

Comment: If I replace `JSON.stringify(place)` with `place`, the results in the console are `Place.stringify: [object Object]`. It doesn't look like Google was already JSONing the object.

Comment: You misunderstand. When you call `JSON.stringify(o)`, it will call `toJSON` on anything inside `o` that has such a method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `place.geometry.location` is a function( `google.maps.LatLng` ), functions may not be transported via JSON

What you see when you log `place.geometry.location` is the returnValue of the  `toString`-method of a `google.maps.LatLng`

Comment: Thank you! Is the solution then to create my own JSON object with the place attributes I need, then send that object via AJAX? Any idea why it would have been working before?

Comment: Yes, it would be a solution(you may use the existing object and overwrite `geometry.location` with the desired value ). I don't know why it has been working before, maybe the JSON-parser has been changed